# Who meets Harrison Wells after the car crash?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, the-flash-2014

As he mentioned to Joe earlier on in the series,  he started work on the particle accelerator shortly after the car crash that killed his fiance.

However in season 1 episode 17 Tricksters,  in a flashback:

> We see that someone resembling Barry's dad appears and steals Harrison's body.

Is this correct?  Is that the same person we see

> After the murder of Barry's mother

?

Comment: how did you make it so that the text is hidden

Comment: @sluger they're [spoilers](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/968/3804) and you just type `>! Paragraph ` before your paragraph.

Answer (score 3):

The guy that shows up is Eobard Thawne.

He had traveled to 2014 from his own timeline, to find and kill Barry Allen before he became the Flash.

But Flash saves his younger self, which is when in a fit of rage, Eobard Thawne kills Barry's mother.

He then tries to time-jump back to his timeline but is unable to do so.
He has lost his speed force for the time-being.

He then goes and sets a trap for Harrison Wells, causing him to crash his car.

Eobard Thawne then uses some sort of future machine to become identical to Wells, killing Wells in the process.

Thawne mentions his name before he proceeds to kill Wells. Thawne also tells Wells that he needs the particle accelerator to be in place in order to go back to his timeline. So after he replaces Wells he starts working on the particle accelerator.

Comment: So the resemblance is just coincidence then?

Comment: Pretty much. Yeah. [eobard thawne](http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/arrow/images/6/63/Eobard_Thawne.png/revision/latest?cb=20160127041404) 
as compared to  [henry allen](http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/arrow/images/a/af/Henry_Allen.png/revision/latest?cb=20151007023433)